# Emacs Org-Mode: Enabling Markdown Exporter

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm trying to enable the Markdown exporter for Org-Mode. According to the [the manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-back_002dends.html#Export-back_002dends) I should "customize `org-export-backends`".

However when I try

> <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> `customize-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `org-export-backends`

...Emacs complains that there is `[no match]` for this variable. I can inspect the variable (using `describe-variable`, so I know it exists) but there is no 'customize' link to click.

Why won't this work? Is my setup broken, and if so, how can I fix it?

(I am running Debian testing (jessie) with org-mode 7.9 if that makes any difference.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of word "customizing" in the manual is a bit misleading (if version of manual matches version of org-mode you are using).

Variable `org-export-backends` is not customizable via customize (its definition was done with `defvar`, as opposed to `defcustom`).  You need to use something like `setq` to set the value you like.

Comment: Your comment on the version of the manual is indeed correct. It looks like I was inadvertently reading the manual for version 8. Frustratingly, there doesn't seem to be much documentation for using the markdown exporter for version 7.9 (even though it is there).

Comment: Yoy may want to use a more recent version.  Here is a description of an easy way of updating it: http://orgmode.org/elpa.html

Comment: Thanks for the extra info about upgrading - very useful. Org-mode in Debian Testing has just moved up to version 8.0.6 to all is good now :-)

Comment: how do I do that via configuration files?